# Cannot find a calculated member in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create a calculated member to convert a string date into date type field in Tableau using a cube data source.

The field name is Offer Start Date in the Offer Dimension in the cube. Here are the steps that I follow :

1) Right click and select 'Calculated Members'.

2) Click on the New button, name the new field 'Converted Offer Start Date' and paste the following MDX :
   IIF(IsDate("Offer Start Date"),CDate("Offer Start Date"),NULL)

3) I did a Check formula and clicked Ok

Now the issue is I cannot find this new Calculated Member anywhere under Offer dimension.Am I missing anything ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked for it in the Measures panel, just below dimensions? When you create a calculated field, Tableau will try to guess whether it is a dimension or a measure